# vue how to send file to backend

Tags: vue.js, post, file-upload, vuejs2, axios

lets say, I have my files in variable `files`.

Normally I send a JSON Object to my server:

```
let person = {
 name = 'alan'
 job = 'it'
};
```

And then I send with axios `post`.

So how can I add the attached file to the object and send it to the server? Because on server-side and in db I need to know which file belongs to which person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Base64 encode in client side and add the encoded string to your post request and decode from server side.

Comment: So then I can just add another string atribute to my person object and assign the string to it, thats all?